# Migrate data from Sybase to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-migration, sybase, data-migration

We have to migrate the data from Sybase to SQL Server. The Adaptive server enterprise driver is added in user DSN but is not getting visible under the providers of SSIS connection managers.

Answer (score 0):

When you are developing an SSIS package in Visual Studio it cannot see a DSN using 64 bit drivers. More than likely the driver you setup your DSN with is a 64 bit driver.

Install a 32 bit version of the driver and reconfigure your DSN to use it.

Comment: *"SSIS can only see 32 bit drivers."* this isn't true. If that were the case, why would you have the option of choosing whether to run in 64bit or 32 bit if it can only use 32bit. Perhaps you're thinking of Visual Studio, which is ***still*** only available as a 32 application.

Comment: @Lamu Correct. Will adjust my wording.

Comment: Thanks Chris and Larnu for quick reply. We have been using the Devart driver to connect to sybase which I believe is 64bit. I was able to do a test connection to sybase with ODBC driver since its already configured but was unable load the tables. It gave a COM component related error so hoping that installing and configuring  32 bit driver will resolve it. Meanwhile another work around is to export the data in csv and pull it in to sql server using ssis packages but this one is long short as the no of tables are 5k+.